# Удалить дубли по нескольким стоблцам из запроса?

Tags: postgresql

В результате запроса SELECT выводятся строки у которых в некоторых столбцах есть дубли.

```
id  color    name       value 
1    red      moscow     300
2    red      moscow     400
3    black    rostov     500
4    red      rostov     500
```

Нужно удалить дубли где одинаковые значения по столбцам color и name.
То есть это записи с id 1 и 2.

Comment: Т.е. полностью удалить строки, встречающиеся более 1 раза, обе копии ? тогда group by по этим 2 полям, к остальным полям (если они нужны) применить любую групповую функцию, например max и условие `having count(1)=1`, после group by, что бы остались только строки, встречающиеся 1 раз

Comment: Например, для red moscow оставить нужно 1 или 2?